# How to update the page breadcrumb when using theme page

Tags: 7, forms, breadcrumbs, entities

I have an entity form(theme page to display it) .
I have used `hook_node_view()` to handle breadcrumbs for nodes.
But I don't find any place to handle this `$breadcrumb` when I have a form and a theme page for it.

This is how I got the `$breadcrumb` for my news.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function news_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type == 'news' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    //BREADCRUMB ////
    $breadcrumb = array();
    $breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
    $breadcrumb[] = l('News', 'news');
    drupal_set_title('News');
    drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
  }
}
```

I have hook functions like:

```
hook_init()
hook_menu()
hook_form()
hook_form_validate()
hook_form_submit()
hook_theme()
hook_preprocess_form()
```

But I don't find a place to work on `$breadcrumb`, or somehow manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for GUI to handle breadcrumbs, take a look at [Custom breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module.
Otherwise, you can manage your breadcrumbs programatically in lot of hooks. The code you've printed is correct, so you can create for example a function with a switch case like this one :

```
function manager_breadcrumbs($form_id) {
  $breadcrumb = array();
  $breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'my_first_form' :
      $breadcrumb[] = l('Category', 'taxonomy/term/1');
      break;
  }
  drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
}
```

And then, call this function in a **hook_form_alter()** like this.

```
function MY_CUSTOM_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  manager_breadcrumbs($form_id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your  time. But I have about 16 forms directed to the same theme page. In case, if I am going to try something from the template file, that is just a waste of time. And also, I have to display the breadcrumb something like "Home >> Form Module >> Form Title"

Comment: If the page show only one form, try using **hook_form_alter()** instead (I will edit the code above)

Comment: Thanks, now I got if from my module's code. I have expanded the switch to get things done.[also edited a mistake in switch syntax in your code]